# How to set print when expression for a text in sub report based on the page number of main report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport, dynamic-reports

I have a main report which contains sub report in footer. I need to hide a text in the sub report on all pages except the first page. I tried to set print when expression using the following expression:

```
new AbstractSimpleExpression<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean evaluate(ReportParameters reportParameters) {
        return reportParameters.getPageNumber() == 1;
    }    
}
```

But it didn't work. I debugged it and found that `reportParameters.getPageNumber()` always returns one which I assume to be the page number of sub report. I checked the available methods in `reportParameters` object and I couldn't found any method to get the page number of main report. Is there any other way to set print when expression for a text in sub report based on the main report's page number?

Comment: Pass it to subreport as a parameter.